# How do I exclude Repositories in Spring tests?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm writing tests for a Controller that uses a `CrudRepository`. Typically, I'd like to isolate the unit test by using mocks instead of the actual repository instances. However, Spring keeps injecting actual Repository proxies, and I don't know how to effectively exclude them.

My unit test look something like:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(TestConfiguration)
@WebAppConfiguration
class ControllerSpec extends Specification {
    ...
}
```

The configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    AccountRepository accountRepository() {
        mock(AccountRepository)
    }

}
```

I've tried annotating the configuration class with `@NoRepositoryBean` but it didn't work. I also tried using `excludeFilters` in `ComponentScan` using regex type, but it also didn't work.

Comment: You may wanna give a try for @Mock private AccountRepository accountRepository; at the class level.

Comment: How about you add setter method for AccountRepository in your controller class. Before executing test just set repo as mock instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation has an `excludes` property that allows users to ignore some auto-configuration features. Most of these are represented by corresponding `*AutoConfiguration` classes. To bypass repositories in particular, the following can be excluded from auto-configuration:

- `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`
- `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`
- `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration`

I'm not really sure which combination of them is the absolute minimum, but it should be relatively easy to do trial-and-error with them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @InjectMock annotation at the top of your controller and @Mock annotation for your repository.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AccountControllerTest {

@InjectMocks
AccountController controller;

@Mock
AccountRepository accountRepository;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using JUnit for testing (at least not directly) so runners won't work.